# When is a complete graph a polyhedral graph?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polyhedra

A *polyhedral graph* is the graph build from the vertices and edges of a *convex* polyhedron (finite intersection of half spaces). For example, the complete graph $K_n$ is the polyhedral graph of the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex, hence can be realized in $n$ dimensions.

[image]

For dimensions $n=1,2,3$ the $K_{n+1}$ is the biggest complete graph that can be realized here. But I read (Optimization, Jarre & Stoer) that in dimension 4 and above this rule breaks down. For example, it is claimed that $K_6$ is a polyhedral graph in four dimensions.

> **Question:** Can you give me an example for a convex polyhedron in four dimensions which realizes $K_6$?

Note that convexity is an important assumption as seen for the [Szilassi polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szilassi_polyhedron), which is a 3-dimensional realization of $K_7$.

**Extra:** What is so special about dimension four that this general rule breaks down here. Which $K_n$ can be realized in $m$ dimensions?

Comment: Look up ``neighbourly polytopes".